# Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Does the picture of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^3+x^2)$ have fuzz around the origin?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Does the picture of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^3+x^2)$ have fuzz around the origin?

Since $x^3+x^2 = x^2(x+1)$, then $$\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^3+x^2)=V(x^2) \cup V(x+1).$$

Therefore, picture of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^3+x^2)$ consists of just two points: $(x-0)$ and $(x+1)$ corresponding to the point $0$ and the point $-1$.

The radical of $(x^3+x^2)$ is the ideal $(x^2+x)$ hence the ring $k[x]/(x^3+x^2)$ is not reduced.

However, does the $V(x^2)$ component tell us that there is "fuzz" around the point $0$?

Comment: Yes, if I were to draw a picture of this scheme, I would draw two points on a line, one (the one at the origin) a bit thicker than the other.

Comment: @BrianShin Would the radical ideal $\operatorname{rad}(x^3+x^2)=(x^2+x)$ have a role in this picture?

Comment: Sure, drawing the picture for $\operatorname{rad}(x^3 +x^2)$ would mean drawing the picture for $(x^3 + x^2)$ but without any fuzz

Comment: @BrianShin Ahh yes, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To think of a picture of the scheme $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^3+x^2)$, we should not think of a picture for $V(x^2) \cup V(x+1) = V(x) \cup V(x+1)$. Although they are equal as sets, $V(x^2) = V(x)$ does not tell us the additional information that attached to the origin.

To draw a picture, as Brian suggested above, we should think of the schemes $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^2)$ as subschemes of the line $\mathbb{A}_k^1 = \operatorname{Spec}k[x]$. Note that a function $f \in k[x]$ vanishes on $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x)$ if and only if $f$ vanishes at $0$ (so nothing special happens); however, $f \in k[x]$ vanishes on $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^2)$ if and only if $f$ and its derivative vanish at $0$. Thus, the point in $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^2)$ has encoded an additional data into the function on it (which is the data of the derivative). The information on derivative tells us that there is some "disembodied" tangent vector attached to the origin so a reasonable picture at the origin is a thicker point. I would like to think about the tangent vector as a nearby point approaching to the origin (that's why the origin looks thicker).

If the embedding to $\mathbb{A}_k^1$ is not interesting enough, try to embed these schemes to $\mathbb{A}_k^2$ (or higher dimension). While the scheme $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x)$ is still a usual point, we have many ways to embed the scheme $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^2)$. Each way of embedding, we will have the origin and a point approaching the origin along some direction (tangent vector of some smooth curve). So again, $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^2)$ is a point together with a tangent vector.